# Webpack 3 to 4, CommonsChunkPlugin to SplitChunksPlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp, bundle

I am trying to update webpack to v4 and i am having issues with CmmonsChunkPlugin.

This is my current simple config

```
new webpackStream.webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'common',
  filename: 'common.bundle.js'
})
```

How would i go about createing the common.bundle.js file with all the common shared modules that i use in all of my js entries.

What i have tried right now is

```
optimization: {
splitChunks: {
  cacheGroups: {
    common: {
      name: 'common',
      filename: 'common.bundle.js',
      chunks: 'all'
    }
  }
}
```

}

But this results in me having a large common.bundle.js file with all of the code in all my js entries files